# How to create datasets in Wave - Need to load datasets from Informatica Cloud

Tags: integration, einstein-analytics, informatica, data-set

I am new to Wave Analytics. I am trying loading datasets from relational database using Informatica Cloud.

Do I need to create datasets in Wave before loading data from Informatica Cloud. If yes, which option should I choose to create datasets in wave: Salesforce; CSV; Informatica Rev?

Or datasets will be created at runtime while running Informatica jobs.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataset using Informatica,

Goto Wave Analytics--> Click "Create" ---> Choose ----> Dataset --> (SELECT A DATA SOURCE) HERE, You have several options(CSV,SF,Informatica Rev, Informatica, Mulesoft,Boomi, etc) to create your dataset.

Thanks,
JamMie